# Difference between a transformed div with various point of origin

Tags: css, math, rotation, transform

I have one two divs (rectangle) that have each the following transforms applied on:

```
translate(100px, 100px) scale(2) rotate(20deg)
```

Those divs are identical except the point of origin varies, one have (0, 0) and the other have (64px, 64px). You can see them here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L7ksC/2/

How can I get the left and top difference between those tho divs?
It can be just a math solution rather then a Javascript one.

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this? :-)

Comment: Doing some DOM manipulation that involves origin-point manipulation. I fail at 6th grade trigonometry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution in [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SV3db/6/).

I used the [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method from jquery, to get top and left. For some angles of rotation the left value will not correspond to the top left corner, but a little trigonometry can sort that out. Please let me know if anything in the jsfiddle is unclear, I'd be happy to explain further.

Keep in mind that the left most point of a box is not the same as the left coordinate of the top point for a 20 degree rotation. In order to calculate the left coordinate I wrote this code:

```
  var scale    = 2;
  var p_height = 128;
  var rotation = 20;

  var add_to_left =scale*p_height*Math.sin(rotation*Math.PI/180);
```

The formula calculates the horizontal distance between the left position and the left coordinate of the top corner. Here is a [much simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SV3db/8/) showing the right triangle I am talking about.

Comment: Its an elegant solution, thanks. The only thing that I do not understand is the '-10' padding which I do not see in the css. Thanks

Comment: In the CSS of the jsfiddle page itself there is 10px padding inside the result box, this is not something I have any control over. Removing the '-10' would give the exact positions of p0 and p1 relative to their parent container. When I was trying to solve the problem I found it helpful to think of the boxes positions prior to rotation as being the same as their translated values, which required compensating for padding.